# En el ciclo de vida de los hooks react cuando actualizas un estado se vuelve a ejecutar el función del componente?

Tags: reactjs

Lo pregunto porque tengo un console log en la funcion principal del componente, y cada ves que cambio un estado se ejecuta ese console.log

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [bgPostColor, setBgPostColor] = useState(undefined);
  const numbers = [1,2,3,,4,5];  


  const changeBgColorPost = number => { 
    switch (number) 
    { case 2: setBgPostColor("blue"); break;
      case 3: setBgPostColor("green"); break;
      case 4: setBgPostColor("yellow"); break;
      case 5: setBgPostColor("red"); break;    
      default: setBgPostColor("white"); break;
    }
  }

  const listItems = numbers.map( number => 
    <span key={number}>

      <label 
      className={"radioLabel radio-"+number} htmlFor={"radio-"+number} onClick={ () => changeBgColorPost(number) }>
      </label>
      <input name="category" style={{ display: 'none' }} type="radio" id={"radio-"+number}/>

    </span>
  )


  console.log("posts")


  return (
      <div>
        <div className="categories">
          {listItems}
        </div>
        <textarea placeholder="Escribe aqui pues, ramon" name="" id="" style={{ background: `${bgPostColor}` }}></textarea>
    </div>
  )

}
export default App;
```

hay agrege el codigo.

Tambien a ese componente le tengo una consulta a traves de axios para obtener una lista de post y la ejecuto dentro del "useEffect" pero no lo vi importante colocarlo aqui

Comment: Agrega el código del cual estás hablando para entender mejor tu problema. Saludos

Comment: ya puse le codigo gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

De por sí los componentes funcionales se actualizan cada vez que su padre es renderizado o recibe unas props nuevas. Imagina que todo el cuerpo de la función es el render de un componente clase. Ahora que tenemos state en estos componentes también provocarán un renderizado,así que debes tener cuidado con los Hooks especialmente con tu arreglo de dependencia, esto ayudará a que el Hook solo se ejecute una vez([]) o cada vez que un prop o state cambié ([prop, state]), y no siempre con cada renderizado que aveces ocasiona mal rendimiento. 
Entonces si, se renderiza cada vez que un state cambia.
Espero sea de ayuda.